# Error code Bot discord 'Bot' object has no attribute 'interaction'

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I've been trying for weeks to make my discord bot use Interactions(commands slash) instead of prefixes and when starting this code

https://github.com/Arion107/DiscordBot/blob/main/command.py

It gives me the error Error: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'interaction' infinitely and I don't know what to do anymore And tried to put bot.interaction.start or interaction.start but it doesn't work, I would appreciate the help

Comment: Please post a [mre] here, not just a link to github (if you get an answer you'll revise the code there, and no one will be able to see what the problem was).

Answer (score 0):

I've adjusted your code slightly using the @tree.command. Hope this works for you.

Whatever commands you want to make just put in another @tree.command and if you want an argument with the command then use @app_commands.describe(nameOfArg="Description that shows").

I hope this answer works.

The main different is:

```
@tree.command(name="dream",
              description="This is the dream command description",
              guilds=guildsList)
@app_commands.describe(task=f"Task?")
    async def dream(interaction, task: str):
            queue.append((interaction, task))
            await ctx.response.defer()
            await ctx.followup.send("Dreaming...", ephemeral=True)
    
@tree.command(name="subscribe",
              description="This is the subscribe description",
              guilds=guildsList)
    async def subscribe(interaction):
        await ctx.response.send_message(
                    "Open the page below to pick your plan and subscribe! https://mee6.gg/m/thedream", ephemeral=True)
```

Also this short part in the on_ready to update the commands in every server that is in guildsList:

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    for guildId in guildsList:
        await tree.sync(guild=discord.Object(id=guildId))

    print("Bot has connected to Discord!")
    bot.loop.create_task(process_queue())
```

Note: You'll need to slap in the server id's into the guildsList

Full:

```
import discord
from discord import Intents, File
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import app_commands
from io import BytesIO
import base64
import asyncio
from keep_alive import keep_alive

intents = Intents.default()
intents.members = True
bot = discord.Client(intents=intents)
tree = app_commands.CommandTree(bot)
guildsList = []

queue = []
users = {}


async def check_command_limit(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    user = interaction.author
    if isinstance(interaction.channel, discord.DMChannel):  # Deshabilitar comando en mensajes privados
        return False
    if "AI" in [role.name for role in user.roles]:
        return True
    if user.id in users and users[user.id] >= 25:
        await interaction.response.send_message(
            f"{user.mention}, Your free dreams have come to an end. Please consider subscribing to one of our plans.To see more details, use the /subscribe command or visit our website at https://mee6.gg/m/thedream",
            ephemeral=True)
        return False
    return True


def increment_user_command_count(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    user = interaction.author
    if user.id in users:
        users[user.id] += 1
    else:
        users[user.id] = 1
    with open('command_count.txt', 'w') as f:
        for user_id, count in users.items():
            f.write(f"{user_id}:{count}\n")


async def generate_dream(interaction: discord.Interaction, task: str):
    try:
        img_data = generateToken64(task)
        decoded_bytes = base64.b64decode(img_data[0])
        image = BytesIO(decoded_bytes)
        await interaction.response.send_message(f" **{task}** - {interaction.author.mention}",
                                                file=File(image, "dream.png"))
    except Exception as e:
        await interaction.response.send_message(
            f"{interaction.author.mention}, The bot is having technical problems, in a few moments it will be operational again.",
            ephemeral=True)
        print(e)


async def process_queue():
    while True:
        if queue:
            interaction, task = queue.pop(0)
            print(f"Processing task '{task}'...")
            if await check_command_limit(interaction):
                increment_user_command_count(interaction)
                await generate_dream(interaction, task)
        await asyncio.sleep(1)


async def start_bot():
    while True:
        try:
            with open('command_count.txt', 'r') as f:
                for line in f:
                    user_id, count = line.strip().split(':')
                    users[int(user_id)] = int(count)

            @bot.event
            async def on_ready():

                for guildId in guildsList:
                    await tree.sync(guild=discord.Object(id=guildId))

                print("Bot has connected to Discord!")
                bot.loop.create_task(process_queue())

            @tree.command(name="dream",
                          description="This is the dream command description",
                          guilds=guildsList)
            @app_commands.describe(task=f"Task?")
            async def dream(interaction, task: str):
                queue.append((interaction, task))
                await ctx.response.defer()
                await ctx.followup.send("Dreaming...", ephemeral=True)

            @tree.command(name="subscribe",
                          description="This is the subscribe description",
                          guilds=guildsList)
            async def subscribe(interaction):
                await ctx.response.send_message(
                    "Open the page below to pick your plan and subscribe! https://mee6.gg/m/thedream", ephemeral=True)

            await bot.start()
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error: {e}")
            await bot.close()


keep_alive()
asyncio.run(start_bot())
```

Also this is based on the following youtube video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jh1CtQW4DTo

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for putting your time in modifying the code, but I have a problem, when I go to execute it I get this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "main.py", line 102, in <module>
     tree = app_commands.CommandTree(bot)
   File "/home/runner/TheCreatorV2/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/app_commands/tree.py", line 134, in __init__
     raise ClientException('This client already has an associated command tree.')
discord.errors.ClientException: This client already has an associated command tree.

Comment: I tried to solve it with ChatGPT but it always tells me

The error you're seeing occurs because you're trying to create a new CommandTree instance for a bot that already has an instance attached to it. To fix this issue, you need to ensure that only one CommandTree instance is created per bot.

Comment: Hey I made a change to how you initialise the bot. I hope that fixes your issue. I originally didnt think it wouldve made a difference but i have a hunch thats maybe the part causing you the issues. Hope that helps

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering me, but when I run the bot I get a message infinitely saying Error: Command 'dream' already registered.

When trying to fix it with ChatGPT it tells me the following
The "'dream' command already registered" error indicates that the "dream" command has already been previously registered. To fix this, you need to make sure that the command is not being registered twice in your code.

Comment: I feel like its because you call the bot.Start() in the while true and maybe its setting up the dream command multiple times and thats why you get the infinite error im guessing starting from the second iteration. Try initialising the bot only once.

Comment: So you should change the await bot.start() to await bot.tree.start() or await bot.tree.command.start()